# Calculating covariance of joint probability mass function in R

Tags: r, statistics, probability, covariance

I have a joint probability mass function of two variables X,Y like here

[image]

How can I calculate the covariance in R?

I created two vectors x,y and fed them into cov(), but I get the wrong result.

How can I do this right?

Thanks in advance and happy coding!

Comment: This is probably better at home on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), the statistics website on the SE network.

Comment: ah thanks, I'll ask there then!

Comment: As far as an R implementation is concerned, please take a look my step-by-step answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Since SO is a coding forum, I'll leave working out the math/stats details up to you. Here is an implementation in R.

1. We start by noting the sample spaces for X and Y

   ```
   # For G
   G <- 0:3;

   # For R
   R <- 0:2;
   ```
2. The joint probability mass function is given by the following matrix

   ```
   joint_pmf <- matrix(
       c(4/84, 12/84, 4/84,
         18/84, 24/84, 3/84,
         12/84, 6/84, 0,
         1/84, 0, 0),
        ncol = 3, byrow = T);
   ```
3. We calculate the population means

   ```
   # For G
   mu_G <- rowSums(joint_pmf) %*% G;

   # For R
   mu_R <- colSums(joint_pmf) %*% R;
   ```
4. We can make use of the theorem `Cov(X, Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]` to calculate the covariance

   ```
   cov_GR <- G %*% joint_pmf %*% R - mu_G * mu_R;
   #           [,1]
   #[1,] -0.1666667
   ```

   where we have used the fact that `E[G] = mu_G` and `E[R] = mu_R` are the respective population means.

Answer (score 0):

From the definitions shown in the figure below,

[image]

The following code uses the definitions verbatim:

```
g <- 0:3          # values of the r.v. G, g in range(G) R_G
r <- 0:2          # values of the r.v. R, r in range(R) R_R
gr <- outer(g, r) # all possible values of product of pairs from G x R. (g,r) in range(GR)
  
f_GR <- matrix(
  c(4/84, 12/84, 4/84,
    18/84, 24/84, 3/84,
    12/84, 6/84, 0,
    1/84, 0, 0),
  ncol = 3, byrow = T)  # Joint PMF f_GR(.)

f_G <- rowSums(f_GR)    # marginal PMF f_G(.)
f_R <- colSums(f_GR)    # marginal PMF f_R(.)

E_G <- sum(f_G*g)       # E[G] = sum(f_G(g)*g)
E_R <- sum(f_R*r)       # E[R] = sum(f_R(r)*r)

E_GR <- sum(gr*f_GR)    # E[GR] = sum(f_GR(g,r)*g*r)

covar <- sum(f_GR*outer(g-E_G,r-E_R))  # E[GR] = sum(f_GR(g,r)*(g-E_G)*(r-E_r)), by (1)
covar
# [1] -0.1666667

covar <- E_GR - E_G*E_R # cov(G, R) = E[GR] - E[G]E[R], by (2)
covar
# [1] -0.1666667
```

Comment: Can you clarify how this is different from the existing answer?

Comment: well, just tried to answer from the definitions of PMFs, clearly pointing out the joint, marginal, expectation formulae from elementary statistics, without using matrix multiplication etc., for a beginner may be easier to understand @Ben Bolke, does that answer your question?